# UIImagePickerController camera cancel not working after browsed several view and opened camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have some 15 to 20 views in app. One is for camera functionality. I have view in that which is set to `UIImagePickerController` to display camera. My problem is, when I open camera directly after app launches, everything works fine. I mean cancel, capture feature of default camera functionality. But suppose, if I browse all other than camera like map, webView,etc and atlast if I open camera, the cancel button is not working(capture button is working in all case).After I capture, controls like retake, use are showing successfully but those buttons also not accessible.

Note: Above problems not occurring when open camera directly after  launch.

These are the things I tried out to solve this issue.

1. Making nil to the previous instance of the `UIImagePickerController` and allocing newly everytime `camera` functionality called.
2. Hiding tabBar everytime before camera opens since I suspect may the area of tabBar be unaccessible.
3. Setting the frame of the view exactly to the phone screen size, so it assures the whole view will be accessible.

**Please note:**

May this will be helpful.

1. **This happens only in iPhone3GS. In all other models, its working great.**
2. I have found, only the portion of the tabBar(which exist in all other view and hides only when camera opened), is not accessible. I found this by pressing all over the buttons and I can access the portion of the button which exist out of the tabBar. May be the below screen shot will be more informative.

[image]

Please share your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Below is the code I used to display camera.

```
-(IBAction)btnCamera_Clicked:(id)sender{

    _imgPicker = nil;
    _imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imgPicker.delegate = self; 
    _imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;     
    _imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
        _imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        _imgPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        _imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = vwCameraOverlay;
        [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:_imgPicker animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is in `vwCameraOverlay` check the size of the overlay, it is blocking the controls.

Comment: @iphonic : I have set the size of view exactly to the screen size. "vwCameraOverlay.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);". If its because of frame size, then it should be occur everytime I use camera.

Comment: No, you overlay should be CGRectMake(0,0,320,480.0-44.0); 44.0 is the Camera Toolbar so your overlay should end before the toolbar starts in Camera view.

Comment: Ok lets assume this solves my problem . But my doubt is, how its working when I open firstly before other views.Ok I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: @iphonic : No this also doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
         [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**Edited:**

And to open controller try

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

It should work.

Comment: Already I have implemented. But the problem, the button itself not accessible(75% of the portion is untouchable).

Comment: It seems that you are adding the camera view over your parent view, is it ? Try presenting the UIImagePickerController as MODAL.

Comment: ya I presenting the imagPickerController as Modal only.This is code I am using to present my camera."[self presentModalViewController:_imgPicker animated:YES];"